# Alternative to jqGrid, just an edit feature with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I've been searching around for a jquery plugin or some js source code that will allow me to implement editing on a html table created with ajax.  I came across jqGrid but I feel like it's a bit overkill and it would resort to me having to create the table on the server side.  Plus, I already wrote the ajax for deleting rows.  All I really need is inline editing of text fields, check boxes, select dropdowns and jQuery ui DatePicker.

**Does anyone know of a plugin or tutorial on how to implement this type of editing into an html table with ajax?  If not, a guideline to writing the js would be very helpful.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best is SlickGrid: [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)

Documentation is still a little light but it's CRAZY fast.  As of this writing, the only way to learn how to use it is to look through the examples:

[Examples](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples)

[Simple example - 1](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html)

Comment: Looks good.  I just downloaded the source and it makes me want to cry

Comment: Best not to look, but the guy that wrote it is seriously a performance genius.  It kills jqGrid on that front.

Comment: I just have no clue how to set it up

Comment: updated with links to the examples.  To start yourself off, just view source on those and modify as you need.  The basic example sounds like a good place to start for your requirements.